# Problema para aplicar .toLowerCase a info traida por promise

Tags: nodejs, express, promesas, backend, get

Tengo la siguiente ruta
getAllPokemons devuelve un array de objetos pokemon traidos desde la base de datos y la api

```
router.get('/pokemons', async (req, res) => {
  const name = req.query.name;
  let allPokemons = await getAllPokemons();
  if(name){
    let pokemonName = allPokemons.filter( p => p.nombre.toLowerCase().includes(name.toLowerCase())
    );
    pokemonName.length ?
    res.status(200).send(pokemonName) :
    res.status(404).send('El pokemon no existe');
  } else {
    res.status(200).send(allPokemons);
  }
})
```

El problema es que toLowerCase() no lo esta reconociendo porque la name y p.nombre le estan llegando como undefined, asumo que la info esta llegando antes y cuando aplica el toLowerCase() aun esta undefined probe haciendo un await para esperar la respuesta de la API pero me sigue dando error, adjunto las funciones que usa el codigo

```
const getInfo = async () => {
  let pokemones = [];
  let respuesta = [];
  const response = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon');
  const data = await response.json();
  data.results.forEach((poke) => {
    pokemones.push(poke)
  });
  for(let pokemon of pokemones){
    await fetch(pokemon.url)
            .then(r => r.json())
            .then( resp => {
              respuesta.push({
                name : resp.name,
                vida: resp.stats[0].base_stat,
                fuerza: resp.stats[1].base_stat,
                defensa: resp.stats[2].base_stat,
                velocidad: resp.stats[5].base_stat,
                altura : resp.height,
                peso : resp.weight,
              })
            })
  }
  return respuesta;
}

const getDbInfo = async () => {
  return await Pokemon.findAll({
    include : {
      model: Type,
      attributes : ['nombre'],
      through: {
        attributes : [],
      }
    }
  })
};

const getAllPokemons = async () => {
  const pokeInfo = await getInfo();
  const dbInfo = await getDbInfo();
  const infoTotal = pokeInfo.concat(dbInfo)

  return infoTotal;
}
```

Comment: Falta ver lo que devuelve `getAllPokemons`. De tu código poco se puede deducir, mas bien se puede especular.

Comment: ¿Ya usaste `.then()`?

Comment: Actualizo pregunta con las funciones que utlizo

Comment: Si use .then(), la idea es traer solo el pokemon que paso por query, hacer la consulta a los pokemones de la base de datos y la api, por eso el getAllPokemons

Comment: Que hay en consola si pones `console.log(allPokemons)` luego de hacer `await getAllPokemons()`?

Comment: Problema solucionado, a nivel de codigo todo esta bien implementando, la cuestion es la API algunas veces tarda unos ms mas para enviar la info, por el momento ya se estabilizo la app, pero estoy aun buscando como mejorar la traida de datos. Me di cuenta de ello al hacer console.log(allPokemons) estaba llegando el arreglo de objetos y a veces era vacio, me toco refrescar muchas veces para darme cuenta de ello